# Remove parent and everything inside it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery to remove a div and all of its content when a child div is clicked. To explain this, here is a working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r0taz01L/40/). Basically I need to remove the `pDiv` when the close button is clicked. So I tried this:

```
$('div').on('click', '.closeDiv', function () {
    $(this).prev().remove();
    $(this).remove();
     $(this).parent().remove();
    $('#upload-file').val("");
});
```

However this doesn't seem to delete the `pDiv`.

Please test the FIDDLE above buy adding an image and then click on the Green close button and then try to add another image and you will see that the previous `pDiv` hasn't been removed.

Could someone please advice on this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your fiddle seems unrelated to the question...?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, sorry about that.. updated the fiddle in my question.

Comment: No problem - I added an answer for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try following and follow the comment i mentioned.

```
$(document).on('click', '.closeDiv', function () {
        $(this).prev().remove(); // i don't know why you need this.. let us know your structure
        //$(this).remove(); you don't need this line
         $(this).parent().remove();
        $('#upload-file').val("");
    });
```

Please find the **[working Fiddle for this](http://jsfiddle.net/r0taz01L/41/)**

Comment: @user2056633 Accept the answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: Seen as this was the accepted answer, could you please add some detail about what the issue is so that you can educate future visitors to the question.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is because you call `$(this).remove()` before you try and do further DOM traversal on the element which no longer exists. Remove that line. Note that you can also just use `closest()` to find the required `.pDiv` element, then remove it, like this:

```
$('#thumbnail').on('click', '.closeDiv', function() {
    $(this).closest('.pDiv').remove();
});
```

Also note that the code in your fiddle uses an odd mix of jQuery and native JS. You should stick to one or the other. You're also doing several processes which aren't needed, such as creating a `canvas` element. Try this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var $thumbnail = $('#thumbnail').on('click', '.closeDiv', function() {
        $(this).closest('.pDiv').remove();
        $('#upload-file').val('');
    });

    var $fileDiv = $("#upload");
    var $fileInput = $("#upload-file").on('change', function(e) {
        var filesVAR = this.files;
        showThumbnail(filesVAR);
    });

    function showThumbnail(files) {
        var file = files[0]
        var $pDiv = $('<div class="pDiv" />').appendTo($thumbnail);
        var $image = $('<img class="imgKLIK5" />').appendTo($pDiv);
        var $div = $('<div class="closeDiv">X</div>').appendTo($pDiv);

        var reader = new FileReader()
        reader.onload = (function(aImg) {
            return function(e) {
                aImg.src = e.target.result;
            };
        }($image[0]))
        var ret = reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/r0taz01L/44/)